# Valves on an electric hot water heater

Tags: water-heater, hot-water

I'm getting ready to replace my GE electric hot water heater. On top there are hot AND cold water valves. When draining the heater, I know to shut the cold water valve. What about the hot water valve? Should that be shut as well?

Answer (score 2):

Only need cold water valve closed. Leave the hot water outlet valve open plus one or more hot water taps open above it to let in air to break vacuum.  Make sure power is off to tank. Drain tank.

Comment: ...and be sure to completely fill the tank before turning the power back on. turn on a hot water faucet until water flows out to be sure it's filled. Otherwise, you'll burn up your elements.